# How to move an object a specific amount ONLY when button is pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've looked through dozens of tutorials and I still can't figure this out.

I have up, down, left, and right buttons that control the movement of a 3D object (in my case, a cannon)

When the player clicks on the left/right arrow buttons, the object will move one unit along the +-X axis.

I got this to work, however the objects move in one direction forever and doesn't stop when the button isn't clicked! How do I make the object only move once when the button is clicked?

```
public class ClickMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject cannon;
    public bool pressed = false;



public void HitButtonLeft()
      {
          if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
          {
              pressed = true;
                  cannon.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(-1000.0f, 0, 0);

          }
      }
      public void HitButtonRight()
      {
          cannon.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(1000.0f, 0, 0);

      }
}
```

I know I have 1000.0f right now, but 1 was way too slow and you could barely see movement. I also tried adding the "GetMouseButtonDown(0)" to keep the loop from running unless the left click is active? (But I wasn't able to figure out how to implement this properly)

I've also found this code everywhere on the web. but for the life of me I cannot figure out how/where to use it:

```
 void update();
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(3 * time.deltatime, 0, 0);
        }
```

What is the best way to do this? I do not have a programmers mindset and have been trying to get this to work for days :( I just really need someone to explain how to use translate if that's the better option. I tried absolutely everything and haven't been able to get it to work! I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, and all the tutorials are not n00b friendly.

Also, I can't seem to be able to use "void Update" as that isn't assignable to a UI button, so I don't even know where to go from here...

Thanks

Update: I also tried the following (super backwards way of doing it) but couldn't get it work work either. Someone please help me figure this out!

````
    {
        while (count < 2)        {

            cannon.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(-1000.0f, 0, 0);
            count += 1;
        }

        while (count2 < 2)
        {
            cannon.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(1000.0f, 0, 0);
            count2 += 1;
            count = 0;
        }
    }```
````

Comment: So -- biggest thing I'd point out here is that you're using `.AddForce`. This is tied into the physics system. Think of it like you're firing the engine on a space ship.  It won't stop unless some other physical force (friction, collision, gravity, etc.) makes it stop. If you really want to just move it exactly one unit, what you want to do is alter its `transform` Vector property. Does that help?

Comment: @DeclanMcKelvey-Hembree I tried transform.translate (etc, etc, etc) but the object wouldn't stop moving! How do I get it to only move one time, when the button is clicked? Or did you mean something else about transform?

Comment: @Zii You need to add some drag on the Rigidbody component.

Comment: @Iggy drag? Do I need it? I don't care about speeding.slowing, I just need the object to move/teleport +3/-3 units along the x axis each time the corresponding buttons are pressed. I feel like there's a much easier way to do this, but I can't figure it out. All UI button tutorials I could find were only for Unity 2D interfaces.

Comment: @Zii ah, well then do this: on left button pressed `this.transform.position += Vector3.left * 3f;` and for right `this.transform.position += Vector3.right * 3f;`

Comment: 'void HitButtonLeft()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.left * 3f;
            Debug.Log("Mouse clicked");
        }
    }
}'

Like so? Doesn't appear to be doing anything to my object on mouse click :( but the debug log does show up in console.

Comment: @Zii does this script attached to your gameObject ? If not you need to have a refence to your gameObject like  `myGameObjectRef.transfrom.position += Vector3.left * 3f;`

Answer (score 0):

Demonstrating object movement :
the position property is expressed in vectors
Vector3 = (x, y, z)
to move an object you need to add two vectors together!
Assume object is at origin then transform.position = Vector3(0, 0, 0)
with x = x position, y = y position, z = z position
now to move an object :

*1 - use* :

```
transform.position = (transform.position + new vector3(1, 0, 0));
```

this moves the object instantaneously, teleports it 1 unit to the right (x-axis)

*2 - use :*

to move it 1 unit to the right (x-axis) :

```
transform.Translate(transform.position + new Vector3(1, 0, 0));
```

this moves the object smoothly to new position.
to move it upward (z-axis) : transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 1). 
Build in to C# for Unity is shorthand for this : 
transform.position.right [.left, .up, .down] this is identical to 
transform.position + new Vector3(1, 0, 0) [+new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) etc...]

Update refreshed 60 frames a second +/-
the `GetKeyDown` is called and to move it 1 full unit ( 1 m ) multiply by 60
the `Getkey` gets called every refresh because as long as the button is pressed it is true
so no need for the * 60, you can ad * speed to move the object at certain speed = * m/sec

Answer (score 0):

a drawing in 2D space of vectors being added = position change in Unity.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OoGN.jpg)

Code :

```
public class HorizontalMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int speed;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        speed = 3;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.Translate((Vector3.left) * Time.deltaTime * 60);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.Translate((transform.position + new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f)) *  Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```